# Conditional statement in c# expression in Razor

Tags: c#, html, razor, expression

How can I write this `if` statement

```
@if (camera.IsInStock)
{
    <span class="text-success" style="float:right">IN STOCK</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="text-danger" style="float:right">OUT OF STOCK</span>
}
```

in expression like this:

```
@(camera.IsInStock ? "<span style='float:right' class='success'>IN STOCK</span>" : "<span style='float:right' class='danger'>OUT OF STOCK</span>")
```

The expression I provided doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to render the HTML markup inside a ternary expression, you should use `Html.Raw` method so that it will not get html encoded by razor.

```
@(camera.IsInStock ? 
        Html.Raw("<span style='float:right' class='text-success'>IN STOCK</span>") 
      : Html.Raw("<span style='float:right' class='text-danger'>OUT OF STOCK</span>"))
```

I personally prefer your first approach as i feel that is more readable. you may also consider creating  helper methods which takes the `IsInStock` flag and return the css class needed and the text needed or even your entire span markup.